# Embed images in SPD 2013 workflow - Mobile

Tags: sharepoint-online, designer-workflow, email, image-display, mobile-view

I am currently on SP Online environment. I am sending an email notification to users when a new item is added. I have referenced many articles and i believe i am following the right process adding the image using

> img=src”********”

Everyone has read access to this image location on SharePoint.

We use outlook here and the image on email for Outlook and OWA appears fine. The problem is with Outlook app on mobile phones. I have added an example below, PFA. It just shows up as Images text, instead of displaying on actual image.

[image: Error]

Please suggest,
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Per my test in my SharePoint online environment, I add the image in the email body in the workflow 2013.

The image can display in the outlook and OWA. But in the outlook mobile app, the image cannot display.

I am afraid that it is the issue in the outlook mobile app.

I suppose it is by design.

Comment: Thanks for testing.